# How to draw shape element faster and make them scale in wpf?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, drawing

I have this problem.

So I have a bunch of data that must be visualized on a canvas (say more than 5000 items). So I draw them as a bunch of vertical rectangles over a horizontal line, some thing like this:

---|--|||||---|---|||---||----|||||||--------

Now, because the canvas is small, I only draw a different amount of rectangles at different zoom level. So if I zoom in more, the line get longer, and more rectangles I can see.

Problem is every time I zoom in, I have to clear the whole canvas, and redaw everything with the new zoom scale. And it is really suck, the drawing is slow and scaling not really nice.

So I wondering is there a way I can achieve a faster drawing, and good zooming (like those vector graph, you can zoom in unlimited)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [ScaleTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx)?

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

See [How to: Scale an Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742560.aspx) too. For performance reasons:

- Freeze your [Freezables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613565.aspx#Freezable_Objects).
- > Update Rather than Replace a RenderTransform
  >
  > You may be able to update a Transform rather than replacing it as the
  >   value of a RenderTransform property. This is particularly true in
  >   scenarios that involve animation. By updating an existing Transform,
  >   you avoid initiating an unnecessary layout calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [ZoomableCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/07/29/zoomablecanvas.aspx)? I haven't used it, but it looks like it's designed to do exactly what you want.